# What is way to access parent component property in child component in AngularJS 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

I have parent and child component, and have some element to hide and show using `<ng-if>` by `isTrue` property value. but currently, facing trouble to do the same.

**Exact Scenario:**

I have a property called 'isTrue' in parent components controller and passing it to child using `isTrue: '<'`. Now, in child component, I need to hide something using `isTrue` property value which I have no issue to do so.

Now. again the cycle repeats the same but this time again I want to hard-reset `isTrue` in the parent component using `isTrueCheck()` and again send back to the child component. now, `isTrue` should set to `true` and sent it to child component.

**Summery:**

> **similarly whenever I call isTrueCheck(), I just want to set 'isTrue' to true and send it to child component.**

I have tried to set it into `$onInit()`.

**Parent controller:**

```
this.isTrue;
this.isTrueCHeck = function(){
    isTrue = true;
};
```

**Child controller:**

```
isTrue: '<'
if (isTrue){
   isTrue= false;
}
```

**Child HTML/template**

```
<div ng-click="isTrueCheck"></div>// Calling to reset `isTrue` property
<div ng-if="$ctrl.isTrue">ele1</div>
<div ng-if="!$ctrl.isTrue">ele2</div>
```

Now, I want to call parent controller and hard reset to true and do the same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your problem.
am I right if I say:

1. You have a parent component and some children
2. You have a variable 'isTrue' set in parent and want to propagate it in children. When 'isTrue' changes in the parent, you want to trigger it in children.

Well, if so, in children you need to implement the $onChange method in your children:

```
isTrue: '<'
```

the one above is your variable passed from parent.

```
//
// React to changes of *one-way bindings* (< and @) of a component
// see http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html
// see https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#onchanges
ctrl.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
    // if isTrue changes, do something
    if (changesObj.isTrue && changesObj.isTrue.currentValue) {
        // do something...
        // ....
    }
}
```

see: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html

and

https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Answer (score -1):

If your HTML is like below you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can access the parent scope as follows

```
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isTrue= $scope.$parent.isTrue;
}
```

If you want to access a parent controller from your view you have to do something like this:

```
<div ng-if="$parent.isTrue">ele1</div>
<div ng-if="!$parent.isTrue">ele2</div>
```

Comment: He's not talking about controllers. It talks about *components*. A new features of Angular 1.5+. Components do not have $scope nor $parent.